How to plot mutiple spiric sections of a torus in a single plot?
Spiric Sections are the cross-sections of a circular torus (radius $ a $) cut by a plane parallel to its axis. It has been extensively discussed in the wikipedia page.
I want to show the cross-sectional areas as shown in the book "The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Geometry by Wells D. G." page-26 (shown below).

The Mathematica codes for Torus and its cross-sectional area are shared below. However, I am unable to plot the exact graph as shown in the aforementioned book using the four different plot tools (RevolutionPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, ContourPlot3D, and Graphics3D). They only show one cross-sectional area at a time as shared below.
RevolutionPlot3D
RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[y > -1]]]

ParametricPlot3D
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[\[Phi]])*Cos[\[Theta]], (2 + Cos[\[Phi]]) *
   Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[y > -1]]]

ContourPlot3D
Block[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 1}, 
 ContourPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + b^2 - a^2)^2 == 
    4 b^2 (x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[y > -2]]]]

 
I thought the problem was with the use of RegionFunction. Therefore, I thought, if I could use the ClipPlanes then it might solve the problem, but it also turned futile.
Graphics3D
Graphics3D[Torus[], Boxed -> False , 
 ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 0.5,1}}], InfinitePlane[{{-0.5, -0.5, 0}, {-0.5, -0.5, 1}, {1, -0.5,1}}]}, ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]


How to plot different crossectional areas at a time as shown in the book(in the first figure)?
Please be kind enough to show me a way.
Thank you.


To keep the meshstyle, we use {Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 30], Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 40]}.
We use RegionFunction to cut the plotting to several pieces and TranslationTransform them.

Clear["Global`*"];
R = 4; r = 1;
ParametricPlot[{R + r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

g[a_, b_] := 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{R + r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, {θ,
     0, 2  π}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
   Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 30], Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 40]}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t, θ}, a <= y <= b]];
list = {g[-(R + r), -(R + r/2)], g[-(R + r/2), -R], g[-R, -(R - r)], 
   g[-(R - r), 0], g[0, R - r], g[R - r, R], g[R, R + r/2], 
   g[R + r/2, R + r]};
Graphics3D[
 Table[GeometricTransformation[list[[i]][[1]], 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 i, 0}]], {i, 1, Length@list}]]



Thank you and could you suggest how to make the hollow torus sloid. Like in the Wikipedia diagram : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval#/media/File:Tor-cass-1-3.svg

@user444  A difficult new question.

We slice the torus up into segments and shift each segment to a new place:
seg = {{-5, -4.5}, {-4.5, -3.5}, {-3.5, 0}, {0, 3.5}, {3.5, 4.5}, {4.5, 5}};
shift = {-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5};

gr = MapThread[
   ParametricPlot3D[{0, #2, 
       0} + {(4 + Cos[\[Phi]])*Cos[\[Theta]], (4 + Cos[\[Phi]])*
        Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2  \[Pi]}, {\[Theta],
       0, 2  \[Pi]}, 
     RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, #1[[1]] < y - #2 < #1[[2]]]] &, {seg, 
    shift}];
Show[gr, PlotRange -> All]



thank you and could you suggest how to make the hollow torus sloid. Like in the Wikipedia diagram : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval#/media/File:Tor-cass-1-3.svg

I am not sure what you mean. Are you looking for a filled torus? You could start with the primitive "FilledTorus".
